# Why sync.Once using atomic in doSlow()?

Tags: go, synchronization

I have a question about `Once.doSlow()`. The source code of `Once` is below:

```golang
// Once is an object that will perform exactly one action.
type Once struct {
    // done indicates whether the action has been performed.
    // It is first in the struct because it is used in the hot path.
    // The hot path is inlined at every call site.
    // Placing done first allows more compact instructions on some architectures (amd64/x86),
    // and fewer instructions (to calculate offset) on other architectures.
    done uint32
    m    Mutex
}

// Do calls the function f if and only if Do is being called for the
// first time for this instance of Once. In other words, given
//  var once Once
// if once.Do(f) is called multiple times, only the first call will invoke f,
// even if f has a different value in each invocation. A new instance of
// Once is required for each function to execute.
//
// Do is intended for initialization that must be run exactly once. Since f
// is niladic, it may be necessary to use a function literal to capture the
// arguments to a function to be invoked by Do:
//  config.once.Do(func() { config.init(filename) })
//
// Because no call to Do returns until the one call to f returns, if f causes
// Do to be called, it will deadlock.
//
// If f panics, Do considers it to have returned; future calls of Do return
// without calling f.
//
func (o *Once) Do(f func()) {
    if atomic.LoadUint32(&o.done) == 0 {
        // Outlined slow-path to allow inlining of the fast-path.
        o.doSlow(f)
    }
}

func (o *Once) doSlow(f func()) {
    o.m.Lock()
    defer o.m.Unlock()
    if o.done == 0 {
        defer atomic.StoreUint32(&o.done, 1)
        f()
    }
}
```

Q: After a goroutine get the lock in `doSlow()`, why using atomic instead of directly let `o.done = 1`, like below:

```golang
if o.done == 0 {
    defer func(){o.done = 1}()
    f()
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: LoadUint32 ist faster than acquiring the lock. StoreUint32 is necessary because the field is read concurrently, without holding the lock.

Comment: @Peter I know atomic is more faster. It can not answer the Q2 if just because of atomic is more faster.

Comment: @JamesShi FYI, you are looking at an older version of the code which was updated last March, see [this](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/ca8354843ef9f30207efd0a40bb6c53e7ba86892#diff-5ec3d154401e5eb1017f8ce94b6b64f0). Though, your question is still valid! I had the same discussion with a colleague around 6 months ago about this and we couldn't arrive at a concrete answer!

Comment: StoreUint32 is necessary because the field is read concurrently, without holding the lock, *by LoadUint32*, right there in the same function.

Comment: @Peter Good! but then why is it `if o.done == 0` and not `if atomic.LoadUint32(&o.done) == 0` ?

Comment: Is it because once the lock is acquired, reading is no problem. Only writing is!!

Comment: Yes, concurrent reading is never a problem.

Comment: @Abdullah Yes. Reading is no problem after acquired the lock. Some friend told me that using atmoic for CPU caches. Each core has it's L1 and L2 cache, and all the cores share L3 cache. If not using atom operation. Think about this situation. At first, variable a is equal to 1. core1 modified veriable a from 1 to 2, and a = 2 changed in L1 and L2 of core1. But a = 1 is L1 and L2 of core2. so core2 do NOT know a has been changed。It leads to data inconsistent between cores. atomic can fix this problem.

Comment: @JamesShi: assuming you're talking about x86, that's not correct, the cpu itself will maintain cache coherency. Different processors have different guarantees, and require different instructions.  If you're only working from Go source code, you can only follow the Go memory model, and you can't make any deeper assumptions at without looking at the compiled machine code and knowing the details of the architecture.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for your advice